# How do we generate mongo drdl files with collections names without word "history" in it?

Tags: mongodb, schema, document

I am using mongosqld adapter for mongo BI connection. We can generate mongo .drdl files for a specific collection or ALL collections in a database. However, I need to generate .drdl files for ALL collections WITHOUT the word "history" in it. Any way we could do that without manually providing the collection names without word "history" in it.

mongodrdl command for a specific collection is:

```
     mongodrdl -d test -c mycollection -o myCollSchema.drdl
```